# Causes when not using the key in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error **'Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of'**, When not adding the key in child component.

Why is this key necessary include here? because without this also component render correctly.

```
component - (parent)

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildKey from './ChildKey';
import './App.css';

class ParentKey extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      keyList: [{
        name: 'key1',
      },{
        name: 'key1',
      },{
        name: 'key1',
      },{
        name: 'key1'
      }]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {keyList} = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={{marginLeft: '40%'}}> 
        <h1>Parent Component</h1> 
        <br/>
        <div>
        {
          keyList && keyList.map((data, index) => <ChildKey name={data.name} />)
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    )  
  }

}

export default ParentKey;
```

**component (children) -**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class ChildKey extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getStyle() {
    return {
      rootStyle: {
        width: '40px',
        height: '40px',
        display: 'block'
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const styles = this.getStyle();
    return (
      <div style={styles.rootStyle}>
        <div>{this.props.name}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary in `keyList && keyList.map((data, index) => <ChildKey name={data.name} />)` because when one row changes React needs to know which row changed and it will update only that specific row. Otherwise React will re-render all the rows and this is not good for the performance

Example: `keyList && keyList.map((data, index) => <ChildKey key={data.name} name={data.name} />)`

Comment: Can you please give me an example for that?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Comment: I know how to use the key. But can you give me an example for what disadvantages if not using the key?

Comment: Let's say you render facebook timeline. The user scrolls to the 100th post and likes it, therefore the thumb should become darker. If the posts have no keys React will block the UI rerendering all the timeline posts, while if there are keys it will only rerender the 100th post

Comment: thanks for the example. But can you please explain me its causes using my example?

Comment: This answer fully answers your question. It may be confusing because it takes a while to understand react's DOM update algorithm.